# VBA ADO SQL too few parameters

Tags: sql, vba, excel-2010

I asked this question before but I am still stuck and unable to put parameters inside a SQL query.

```vb
Public Function testInsert(tableName As String, dType As String, role As String, 
FiscalYear As String)
  Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
  Dim conn As ADODB.connection
  Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
  Dim connectionString As String
  Dim SQL As String

  Set conn = New ADODB.connection
  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

  DBPath = "path\to\file.xlsm"
  connectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath &";HDR=Yes';"
  SQL = "INSERT INTO [" & tableName & "$] ([Year], [Type], [role]) VALUES (p1, p2, p3)"

  'Open connection
  conn.Open connectionString

  'Set command text
  cmd.CommandText = SQL
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

  'Set connection
  cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

  'Set paramters in SQL query
  Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("p1", adInteger, adParamInput)
  cmd.Parameters.Append prm
  cmd.Parameters("p1").Value = 1

  Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("p2", adInteger, adParamInput)
  cmd.Parameters.Append prm
  cmd.Parameters("p2").Value = 2

  Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("p3", adInteger, adParamInput)
  cmd.Parameters.Append prm
  cmd.Parameters("p3").Value = 3

  cmd.Execute
  conn.Close

 End Function
```

I am using VBA inside of excel-2010 and I am running the query against an external excel file on my computer. I get a too few paramaters expecting three error.

Please note this code works if the values are string literals so the issue is with the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't follow the reply from yesterday :( You didn't need that Prm variable, but if you used it, then you should use one for the parameter.

```vb
Public Function testInsert(tableName As String, dType As String, role As String, 
FiscalYear As String)
  Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
  Dim conn As ADODB.connection
  Dim prm1 As ADODB.Parameter
  Dim prm2 As ADODB.Parameter
  Dim prm3 As ADODB.Parameter
  Dim connectionString As String
  Dim SQL As String

  Set conn = New ADODB.connection
  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

  DBPath = "path\to\file.xlsm"
  connectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath &";HDR=Yes';"
  SQL = "INSERT INTO [" & tableName & "$] ([Year], [Type], [role]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

  'Open connection
  conn.Open connectionString

  'Set command text
  cmd.CommandText = SQL
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

  'Set connection
  cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

  'Set paramters in SQL query
  Set prm1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p1", adInteger, adParamInput)
  cmd.Parameters.Append prm1
  cmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = 1

  Set prm2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p2", adInteger, adParamInput)
  cmd.Parameters.Append prm2
  cmd.Parameters("@p2").Value = 2

  Set prm3 = cmd.CreateParameter("@p3", adInteger, adParamInput)
  cmd.Parameters.Append prm3
  cmd.Parameters("@p3").Value = 3
```

You didn't need those prm1, prm2, prm3 at all:

```vb
'Set paramters in SQL query
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@p1", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@p2", adInteger, adParamInput)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@p3", adInteger, adParamInput)

cmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = 1
cmd.Parameters("@p2").Value = 2
cmd.Parameters("@p3").Value = 3
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I did and I got the same error expecting three paramaters

Comment: Sure but I can't use real data and it will have to be tomorrow on my personal computer if that is ok?

Comment: @User, no it wouldn't work this Saturday. But if you like I can make it today between (3 PM - 7 PM EST).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176884/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-mathieu-guindon).

Answer (score 0):

Name Parameter with '@' at begining like @p1

```vb
Public Function testInsert(tableName As String, dType As String, role As String, 
FiscalYear As String)
  Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
  Dim conn As ADODB.connection
  Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
  Dim connectionString As String
  Dim SQL As String

  Set conn = New ADODB.connection
  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

  DBPath = "path\to\file.xlsm"
  connectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath &";HDR=Yes';"
  SQL = "INSERT INTO [" & tableName & "$] ([Year], [Type], [role]) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)"

  'Open connection
  conn.Open connectionString

  'Set command text
  cmd.CommandText = SQL
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

  'Set connection
  cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

  'Set paramters in SQL query
  Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@p1", adInteger, adParamInput)
  cmd.Parameters.Append prm
  cmd.Parameters("@p1").Value = 1

  Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@p2", adInteger, adParamInput)
  cmd.Parameters.Append prm
  cmd.Parameters("@p2").Value = 2

  Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@p3", adInteger, adParamInput)
  cmd.Parameters.Append prm
  cmd.Parameters("@p3").Value = 3

  cmd.Execute
  conn.Close

 End Function
```

Comment: Ok but not It saids too few parameters expecting three.

Comment: give different name to each parameter like prm1, prm2, prm3